# “Faire de quelqu’un”?

Tags: grammaire

I saw this sentence on Wikipedia:

> La sœur du dirigeant nord-coréen, Kim Yo-jong a assisté à cette cérémonie, ce qui fait d'elle le premier membre de la dynastie nord-coréenne des Kim à se rendre en Corée du Sud depuis la fin de la guerre de Corée.

I would have expected this to read as “...ce qui la fait le premier membre...” rather than “...ce qui fait d’elle le premier membre...”

Why is that?

Comment: If the phrase was referring to one or more objects, you could construct it with *en* as in *le bitcoin n'a aucune valeur intrinsèque, ce qui en fait la plus importante escroquerie pyramidale de l'histoire*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rare fixed sequence "subject pronoun *faire* noun" is used to describe a promotion to a new title :

> *Je vous fais chevalier de la Légion d'honneur.*
>
> *[Qui t'a fait roi ?](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldebert_Ier_de_La_Marche)*

No article is allowed between *faire* and the new status.

> *Je vous fais <s>un</s> chevalier...*
>
> *Qui t'a fait <s>le</s> roi ?*

When an article or something not a title follows, we must switch to the alternate and common form "*faire de* pronoun something":

> *Je fais de vous le premier chevalier de la Légion d'honneur de cette cérémonie.*
>
> *Ça a fait de lui le plus jeune des rois de France.*

Thus:

> *...ce qui fait d'elle le premier membre de la dynastie...*